Very weird random UI bugs in React Native (with Nativewind installed) on iOS
I am encountering some very random UI bugs in our RN app, that range all over the place (on iOS). In RN 0.75, they only show up in release mode (not in dev client) and in 76, they also show up in devClient.

For example in some cases this very simple component gets distorted in a weird way:
import { View } from "react-native";

interface PaginationDotProps {
    isActive: boolean;
}

export const PaginationDot: React.FC<PaginationDotProps> = ({ isActive }) => (
    <View
        style={{
            width: 8,
            height: 8,
            backgroundColor: isActive ? "black" : "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
            borderRadius: 4,
        }}
    />
);



How can we debug this, or what could be the reason? it seems like it is a bug inside react native framework, or maybe related to an installed package.
This is our package.json (all packages latest up to date as of today):
{
...
    "scripts": {
        "start:dev": "APP_VARIANT=dev pnpm expo start --dev-client --scheme hivemind-dev",
        "android:dev": "APP_VARIANT=dev expo run:android",
        "ios:dev": "APP_VARIANT=dev expo run:ios",
        "android:staging": "APP_VARIANT=staging expo run:android",
        "ios:staging": "APP_VARIANT=staging expo run:ios",
        "android:prod": "APP_VARIANT=prod expo run:android",
        "ios:prod": "APP_VARIANT=prod expo run:ios",
...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@dev-plugins/react-query": "^0.0.7",
        "@expo-google-fonts/fira-code": "^0.2.3",
        "@expo-google-fonts/noto-sans": "^0.2.3",
        "@expo-google-fonts/outfit": "^0.2.3",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.4",
        "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.4.0",
        "@likashefqet/react-native-image-zoom": "^4.2.0",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "2.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app-check": "^21.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.4.0",
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.1.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "7.0.1",
        "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "7.0.1",
        "@react-navigation/native": "7.0.0",
        "@sentry/react-native": "^6.1.0",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.59.20",
        "@uidotdev/usehooks": "^2.4.1",
        "clsx": "^2.1.1",
        "expo": "~52.0.3",
        "expo-application": "~6.0.1",
        "expo-av": "~15.0.1",
        "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
        "expo-build-properties": "~0.13.1",
        "expo-dev-client": "~5.0.1",
        "expo-document-picker": "~13.0.1",
        "expo-font": "~13.0.0",
        "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
        "expo-image": "~2.0.0",
        "expo-localization": "~16.0.0",
        "expo-router": "~4.0.2",
        "expo-sharing": "~13.0.0",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.28.4",
        "expo-store-review": "~8.0.0",
        "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.1",
        "expo-updates": "~0.26.4",
        "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.0",
        "marked": "15.0.0",
        "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
        "openapi-fetch": "^0.13.0",
        "openapi-react-query": "^0.2.4",
        "posthog-react-native": "^3.3.10",
        "posthog-react-native-session-replay": "^0.1.6",
        "prism-react-renderer": "^2.4.0",
        "react": "18.3.1",
        "react-content-loader": "^7.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.76.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
        "react-native-marked": "^6.0.5",
        "react-native-pager-view": "6.5.0",
        "react-native-purchases": "^8.2.6",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.14.0",
        "react-native-screens": "4.0.0",
        "react-native-svg": "15.8.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.8.1",
        "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.4",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.14",
        "text-encoding-polyfill": "^0.6.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
        "@biomejs/biome": "1.9.4",
        "@types/marked": "~6.0.0",
        "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
        "openapi-typescript": "^7.4.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
        "typescript": "~5.6.3"
    },
    "private": true,
    "packageManager": "pnpm@9.12.3"
}


Same problem with similar packages (rn 0.76.2, expo 52.0.7, react-navigation 7.x, reanimated 3.16.1. but without NATIVEWIND. Did you found a solution? Are you on new architecture?

Unfortunately still no solution. We are suspecting it has to do with react-native-marked dependency which is outdated, and will switch it out soon. Can you check your package.json? maybe you have some old packages

@AlessandroBottamedi It was related to this Issue: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/issues/914 . should be solved with an upgrade of the library
